# cannot link homebrew emacs

Tags: macos, emacs, homebrew, symlink

Recently I uninstalled and reinstalled Homebrew entirely on my macbook (OSX 10.9.5) because there was some problem with my Python. Then I reinstalled all the programs in Homebrew and everything worked fine except for Emacs. When I tried to link emacs

```
$ brew link emacs
Linking /Users/myname/homebrew/Cellar/emacs/24.3... 21 symlinks created
```

I expected it to create a shortcut in `Applications` and I open the Emacs GUI from there, but Emacs is not showing up there and I don't know how I can open the GUI. What did I do wrong and how can I link my Emacs?

Comment: This may not be what you want to hear, but there is really no reason to use homebrew or macports.  You can download the latest stable release for OSX already prebuilt, or even a nightly developer build if you so desire:  http://emacsformacosx.com/  The advantage is that all the source files are within the same package.app -- i.e., Emacs.app, which can be seen with the Finder by showing the package contents (i.e., right click on Emacs.app).  While homebrew and macports fans will say that everything is **almost** in one central location, that is largely a matter of opinion.

Comment: I'm not against the idea, it's just people told me about homebrew and that's how I installed Emacs last time (and it worked). I just don't know why it doesn't work anymore. If I can't get this fixed tomorrow I'll try your method.

Answer (score 1):

Try running it from the command line to see what's wrong:

```
emacs --debug-init
```

The program is likely not able to find some elc files or something among those lines.

If all fails, try using the master branch (I update my emacs frequently, such as today).

```
brew install emacs --HEAD --use-git-head --cocoa --srgb --with-xml2 && brew linkapps
```